# Converting graphml to image

Tags: c#, xml, graph, grid, hexagonal-tiles

I have this script that creates a `.graphml` file, and it looks great in yEd ([Link to software](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)), but I'm trying to automate the extra step of having this file, opening it in a different program, doing some edits in there etc etc.

I was wondering if there was some way to automate this into a png image, preferably a hexagonal grid or Vornoi in C#, depending on whether or not each node is connected to exactly 6 or not.

The `.graphml` file structure looks as follows:

```xml
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="d2" for="node" attr.name="value" attr.type="long" />
  <key id="d1" for="node" attr.name="y" attr.type="long" />
  <key id="d0" for="node" attr.name="x" attr.type="long" />
  <graph edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="(0, 1)">
      <data key="d0">0</data>
      <data key="d1">1</data>
      <data key="d2">0</data>
    </node>
    .
    .
    .
    <node id="(39, 38)">
      <data key="d0">39</data>
      <data key="d1">38</data>
      <data key="d2">4</data>
    </node>
    <edge source="(0, 1)" target="(1, 1)"></edge>
    <edge source="(0, 1)" target="(0, 2)"></edge>
    .
    .
    .
    <edge source="(39, 38)" target="(38, 39)"></edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

The value is a direct one-to-one mapping of the node's colour.

And the coordinates are in the following pattern if it were a regular hexagonal grid:

[image]

Hope this query makes sense!
Kind regards.